# Why does this VBA index statement give an error?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

In Excel

```
Dim arr1 As Variant
arr1 = WorksheetFunction.Index(Cells, Evaluate("row(1:100)"), Array(1, 7, 4, 3, 2))
arr1 = Application.Index(Cells, Evaluate("row(1:100)"), Array(1, 7, 4, 3, 2))
```

The first attempt to assign a value to `arr1` fails with an error 13 (Type Mismatch), but the second attempt works fine.

However, while the WorksheetFunction object is part of the Application object, the Application object itself appears to have no "index" method. Yet the code works. Any ideas why?

For what it's worth,

```
arr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Cells, Evaluate("row(1:100)"), Array(1, 7, 4, 3, 2))
```

fails with an error 13 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel functions invoked through `WorksheetFunction` and through `Application` are *supposed* to do the same thing but they differ in many aspects, because they were written at different times and by different teams.

`WorksheetFunction.Index` expects the second argument to be a *number*. This seems to be a "mistake" in writing its prototype, because the actual `INDEX` function of Excel accepts arrays for the second argument. Strangely enough, the third argument of `WorksheetFunction.Index` accepts arrays, because it was declared as `Variant` in the prototype. The mistake occurred only at the second argument which was declared `As Double`, hence the `type mismatch`.

There are other known differences between `WorksheetFunction.doStuff` and `Application.doStuff`. i.e.:

- The former raises a runtime error if errors occur in the calculation. The latter simply returns an *error variant* which you can check by code using `IsError`
- The former functions appear in Intellisense but in a very vague, almost useless way.

I always prefer to invoke the Excel functions through the `Application` object.